# How to check if Django form contains any data?

Tags: python, django

I have Django function view with two forms inside. What is the best solution to detect which form has data typed by user? I know how `form.is_valid()` works, but still I want to check firstly which form was filled with data.

My code:

```
def edit_profile_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        edit_form = EditProfileForm(request.POST)
        pass_form = ChangePasswordForm(request.POST)
        # here I want to detect which form has data inside,
        # and then save this form
    else:
        edit_form = EditProfileForm()
        pass_form = ChangePasswordForm()

    template = get_template("profiles/profile_edit.html")
    variables = RequestContext(request, {'edit_form': edit_form, 'pass_form': pass_form})
    output = template.render(variables)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have two different actions/views for the forms then the form that has data is the one that the user clicked submit on.

You could, like you say, just check what the form errors actually are or make a method on your forms for `is_filled_in` but this all seems overkill to me.